# Netbeans does not automatically deploy to GlassFish (On Mac)

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, netbeans, glassfish-4.1

Im trying to run a Java Web/Web Application by Netbeans (Version 8.2). The project builds without any compile errors. But it does not deploy to the GlassFish Server (version 4.1.1) automatically. Instead, it gives the following output.

```
ant -f /Users/kusal/Documents/CS/Projects/IG/IG/IG -Dnb.internal.action.name=run -Ddirectory.deployment.supported=true -DforceRedeploy=false -Dnb.wait.for.caches=true -Dbrowser.context=/Users/kusal/Documents/CS/Projects/IG/IG/IG run
init:
deps-module-jar:
deps-ear-jar:
deps-jar:
library-inclusion-in-archive:
library-inclusion-in-manifest:
/Users/kusal/Documents/CS/Projects/IG/IG/IG/nbproject/build-impl.xml:874: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Users/kusal/Documents/CS/Projects/IG/IG/IG/nbproject/build-impl.xml:296: 
Cancelled by user.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 7 seconds)
```

In the Java DB Process Window following is logged:

```
Fri Sep 14 17:37:30 IST 2018 : Security manager installed using the Basic server security policy.
Fri Sep 14 17:37:48 IST 2018 : Apache Derby Network Server - 10.10.2.0 - (1582446) started and ready to accept connections on port 1527
```

In Netbeans IDE Log:

```
WARNING [org.openide.util.WeakListenerImpl]: Can't remove java.beans.PropertyChangeListener using method org.netbeans.modules.editor.NbEditorDocument.removePropertyChangeListener from org.netbeans.modules.editor.NbEditorDocument@44580632, mimeType='text/x-jsp', kitClass=null, length=4725, version=1, file=org.netbeans.modules.web.core.jsploader.JspDataObject@b43e807[/Users/kusal/Documents/CS/Projects/IG/IG/IG/web/Pages/ig_accounts_home.jsp@565558d6:75a3ce02]
Even though the source level of /Users/kusal/Documents/CS/Projects/IG/IG/IG/web:/Users/kusal/Documents/CS/Projects/IG/IG/IG/src/java is set to: 1.8, java.lang.AssertionError cannot be found on the bootclasspath: /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/enterprise/modules/ext/javaee7-endorsed/javax.annotation-api.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/enterprise/modules/ext/javaee7-endorsed/javax.xml.soap-api.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/enterprise/modules/ext/javaee7-endorsed/jaxb-api-osgi.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/enterprise/modules/ext/javaee7-endorsed/jaxws-api.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/enterprise/modules/ext/javaee7-endorsed/jsr181-api.jar
Changing source level to 1.3
SEVERE [org.openide.util.Exceptions]
An error occurred during parsing of '/Users/kusal/Documents/CS/Projects/IG/IG/IG/web/Pages/ig_register_student.jsp'. Please report a bug against java/source and attach dump file '/Users/kusal/Library/Application Support/NetBeans/8.2/var/log/ig_register_student_1.dump'.
An error occurred during parsing of '/Users/kusal/Documents/CS/Projects/IG/IG/IG/web/Pages/ig_register_student.jsp'. Please report a bug against java/source and attach dump file '/Users/kusal/Library/Application Support/NetBeans/8.2/var/log/ig_register_student_1.dump'.
Caused: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Check.checkImportedPackagesObservable(Check.java:3679)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.TypeEnter.finishImports(TypeEnter.java:235)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.TypeEnter.complete(TypeEnter.java:220)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol.complete(Symbol.java:591)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$ClassSymbol.complete(Symbol.java:1106)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Enter.complete(Enter.java:728)
    at org.netbeans.lib.nbjavac.services.NBJavadocEnter.main(NBJavadocEnter.java:84)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.enterTrees(JavaCompiler.java:1008)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.enter(JavacTaskImpl.java:369)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.enter(JavacTaskImpl.java:311)
    at org.netbeans.modules.java.source.parsing.JavacParser.moveToPhase(JavacParser.java:630)
    at org.netbeans.modules.java.source.parsing.JavacParser.getResult(JavacParser.java:496)
    at org.netbeans.modules.java.source.parsing.JavacParser.getResult(JavacParser.java:163)
    at org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.TaskProcessor.callGetResult(TaskProcessor.java:631)
    at org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.SourceCache.getResult(SourceCache.java:262)
    at org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.TaskProcessor$RequestPerformer.run(TaskProcessor.java:798)
    at org.openide.util.lookup.Lookups.executeWith(Lookups.java:304)
    at org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.TaskProcessor$RequestPerformer.execute(TaskProcessor.java:725)
[catch] at org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.TaskProcessor$CompilationJob.run(TaskProcessor.java:686)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:514)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:1443)
    at org.netbeans.modules.openide.util.GlobalLookup.execute(GlobalLookup.java:68)
    at org.openide.util.lookup.Lookups.executeWith(Lookups.java:303)
    at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:2058)
ALL [null]: An error occurred during parsing of '/Users/kusal/Documents/CS/Projects/IG/IG/IG/web/Pages/ig_register_student.jsp'. Please report a bug against java/source and attach dump file '/Users/kusal/Library/Application Support/NetBeans/8.2/var/log/ig_register_student_1.dump'.
SEVERE [null]: Last record repeated again.
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.TaskProcessor]: Task: org.netbeans.modules.csl.hints.GsfHintsProvider@581d81c5 : class org.netbeans.modules.csl.hints.GsfHintsProvider ignored cancel for 67 ms.
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.csl.editor.semantic.MarkOccurrencesHighlighter]: MarkOccurencesHighlighter: Cannot get document!
INFO [glassfish]: Storing GlassFish Server 4.1.1 atributes
WARNING [org.netbeans.modules.java.j2seplatform.platformdefinition.J2SEPlatformImpl]: No sun.boot.class.path property in platform JDK 10 (Default), broken platform?
WARNING [org.openide.util.WeakListenerImpl]: Can't remove java.beans.PropertyChangeListener using method org.netbeans.modules.editor.NbEditorDocument.removePropertyChangeListener from org.netbeans.modules.editor.NbEditorDocument@6fee39de, mimeType='text/x-jsp', kitClass=null, length=10969, version=1, file=org.netbeans.modules.web.core.jsploader.JspDataObject@45fbaed7[/Users/kusal/Documents/CS/Projects/IG/IG/IG/web/Pages/ig_register_student.jsp@93230df3:5a6d4831]
```

However, the war file can be manually can be deployed on the server and can be run without any issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Happens when a previously deployed application is already exists in the GlassFish server. Try the following.

1. Stop your server/domain
2. empty the domain[x]/autodeploy/ folder
3. empty the domain[x]/osgi-cache/ folder
4. restart your server/domain and see if your deployment now works.